# currentTime() in video.js

Tags: video.js

The following is my code which is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var myPlayer;

videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){

                    myPlayer = this;
if(myPlayer.currentTime()>3)
{
    
    
    
        alert("STARTED");

});

});
```

Comment: Sorry. What is your question? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: The alert is not coming. I dont know whats wrong with this code.

Comment: I want the alert to be displayed right after the video completes 3 seconds.

Comment: The `ready` event will only occur and run your code once, when the video is initially loaded. The current time at that point is likely `0`. Though, you should be able to use the [`timeupdate` event](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Eventstimeupdate) to respond to playback reaching a certain time.

Comment: so can you suggest the changes that i should make in order to run the code.

Comment: I think you need to go back a step and explain what you are trying to achieve. Testing whether the current time > 3 on the ready event makes no sense - you should expect to *not* receive an alert. There are other events such `timeupdate` (as mentioned) and `playing` which may be more appropriate, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `ready` event only occurs once, when the video initially loads. At that point, the current time is likely `0`.

```
console.log(myPlayer.currentTime()); // 0
```

To continue checking the time as it changes, you should be able to use the [`timeupdate` event](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Eventstimeupdate).

```
myPlayer = this;
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function () {
    // ...
});
```

Though, note that this event occurs multiple times per second. So, to avoid spamming yourself with alerts, you'll probably want to keep track whether 3 seconds have already passed.

```
var threshold = 4;
var thresholdReached = false;

myPlayer = this;
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function () {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= threshold && !thresholdReached) {
        thresholdReached = true;
        alert('Started');
    }
});
```